# How to set number of elements to show in a CarouselSlider per page, using carousel_slider in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a vertical carousel slider using [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) but there's a huge empty space between elements and I can't display the previous element on the screen. What is the best way to remove the empty space and also show the previous element.

My screen is set as follows

```
Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            
          ),
        ),
//Carousel built here
        Expanded(
                child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                  itemCount: cars.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, pageViewIndex) => CarTile(
                    car: cars[index],
                    onpress: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                CarDetailsScreen(car: cars[index]))),
                  ),
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ],
    );
```

CarTile code is as follows:

```
class CarTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Car car;
  final VoidCallback onpress;
  const CarTile({super.key, required this.onpress, required this.car});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onpress,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network(
              height: 150,
              width: size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              car.image,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    child: Text(
                      car.features[0],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    child: Text(
                      car.features[1],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  '${car.brand} ${car.model}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Text(
                  'Tsh. ${NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(car.price)} / hr',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text('${car.year}'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my current results
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the disableCenter option inside CarouselOptions, like this:

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
  itemCount: cars.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index, pageViewIndex) => CarTile(
    car: cars[index],
    onpress: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => CarDetailsScreen(car: cars[index]))),
  ),
  options: CarouselOptions(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    disableCenter: true,
    enlargeCenterPage: true,
  ),
);
```